# Seaborn plot bring lines to front

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Been reading different solutions and trying things for hours so I officially need help. I am plotting a bunch of lines using seaborn pointplot. I am then adding a mean line and a reference line that I would like to be on top of these other lines. No matter what I do with zorder or changing the order of the code, the plot comes out exactly the same (in the wrong order with the black mean line below all the other lines). Here is the code I have:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

g = sns.pointplot(x='months_since_first_month',
              y='revenue_retention',
              hue='index',
              data=companies,
              estimator=np.mean,
                  zorder=1
                 )

sns.pointplot(x='months_since_first_month',
              y='revenue_retention',
              data=companies,
              estimator=np.mean,
              color='black',
              linewidth=4,
              ci=None,
              zorder=10
             )

g.get_legend().remove()

plt.axhline(y=1.0, color='blue', linestyle='--',linewidth=4)

plt.title('Revenue Retention by Company',size=14)
plt.ylabel('Revenue / First Month Revenue',size=14)
```

[image: results]

Comment: Can you add some demo data? And import the libraries inside your code?

Answer (score 1):

Without data I cannot reproduce your result, but I guess what is missing is in the second `pointplot`, the axis should be specified so that two plots are plotting in the same axis:

```py
sns.pointplot(x='months_since_first_month',
              y='revenue_retention',
              data=companies,
              estimator=np.mean,
              color='black',
              linewidth=4,
              ci=None,
              zorder=10,
              ax=g, # add this line
             )
```

You could give it a try, if this doesn't work, then I need the data to detect problem...